# How to save a variable from within the integration with ode113?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have an ODE to be integrated with `ode113`. Inside the function that describes the derivatives I compute some variables that I would like to "save" (either store into a file or into an array). How can I do that?

Here is an example (adapted from the documentation). Run the following script:

```
global number_of_calls
number_of_calls = 0;

[t, y] = ode113(@myfunc, [0 10], 0);
plot(t,y,'-o')
fprintf('Number of calls of ''myfunc'': %d\n', number_of_calls)
fprintf('Number of elements of ''t''  : %d\n', length(t))
```

which calls the function containing the ODE to be integrated:

```
function dydt = myfunc(t, y)

global number_of_calls

dydt = 2*t;
a = 2*y; % <--- how can I save a?

number_of_calls = number_of_calls + 1;

end
```

I thought of writing to file the values of `a` from inside `myfunc`, but as you can see `myfunc` is called multiple times before actually storing the current value for the independent variable, `t`, and in the end I would have two arrays `a` and `t` of different size.

Comment: Why don't you treat is similarly to `number_of_calls`?

Comment: @Wolfie: I thought of doing something like appending to a: `a(end+1)=current_a;` but I would still have `a` and `t` of different lengths. Or isn't this what you meant?

Comment: @Wolfie: I think the issue is that `myfunc` is called a few times during some initialization steps before the integration, so it's called more times than there are values in the returned `t` and `y` data. Is this correct, Pier?

Comment: @Wolfie: Yes, as I understand it. `ode113` is a _variable_-step integration, so I think `myfunc` is called multiple times before each step in order to actually compute the current width of the step.

Comment: @PierPaolo: Ah, I see. Yes, it makes multiple calls per timestep as well as some initial calls.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/279302
Try following Step 1,2,3 mentioned at the end. Make a a vector, keep call, then add a second call with [dydt,a]...

Comment: `a` can vary at a given `t`, so *which* value of `a` do you want?
 Also is a literally `2*y` in your example? If it's defined in terms of `y` then you can just calculate it afterwards...

Comment: @Wolfie: no, the example is a extremely simplified version of my code, I cannot compute `a` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can write `myfunc` to do this. It saves the results to a global vector `a`, which must be set to `[]` before each call to [`ode113`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode113.html). It uses a [persistent variable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) to keep track of the previous time step:

```
function dydt = myfunc(t, y)

  dydt = 2*t;
  temp = 2*y;  % Extra value to save

  global a
  persistent tPrevious
  if isempty(a)  % Initialize
    a = temp;
  elseif (t > tPrevious)  % Moving to a new time step, so add an element
    a = [a; temp];
  else  % Refining time step downwards or recomputing at the same time step
    a(end) = temp;
  end
  tPrevious = t;  % Store prior time step

end
```

And you can check that it's working like so:

```
global a;
a = [];
[t, y] = ode113(@myfunc, [0 10], 0);
isequal(2.*y, a)

ans =
  logical
   1       % a exactly equals 2.*y
```